# Encrypt my disk without laborious reinstallation

Tags: dual-boot, encryption

My laptop is running a dual boot (Ubuntu 20.04, Windows 10).
I want some safety in case of stolen laptop. Nothing is encrypted for the moment.

Is there way to enable  ̶f̶u̶l̶l̶ ̶d̶i̶s̶k̶ ̶e̶n̶c̶r̶y̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ some kind of encryption without having to laboriously manually reinstall all my software/preference on both windows and ubuntu ?

Maybe with hardware encryption  ?
Hardware:
Thinkpad T14s (intel)

Comment: Full disk encryption mandates a single OS (*not dual boot*) as windows & Ubuntu cannot share a single partition (*but live on different file-systems thus different partitions*). Your encryption will need to be partition based (not full disk).

Comment: In short, no. However, one option might be to add a second nvme or m2 ssd to your computer. Reinstall both operating systems, one per disk, and encrypt both.

Comment: If you're after hardware encryption - that is hardware specific (ie. you need a Thinkpad site, this is a Ubuntu support site). IBM used to offer very good hardware encryption on thinkpads; but I switched to using software encryption prior to Lenovo purchasing the thinkpad production line...  Encryption support varies on model though (ie. you need thinkpad/hardware advice for hardware questions!)